# Videojs 7 silvermine videojs-chromecast not loading button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chromecast, video.js

I am currently using videojs 7.4.1 on a ruby on rails application.

I have decided to use the chromecast and airplay plugins by silvermine. All the javascripts seem to load without any errors. However, the buttons do not appear on the player?!?!? Please help!

https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-chromecast
https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-airplay

Here is my video tag

```
<video-js id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered vjs-default-sk in"
controls
autoplay
poster="my-poster.png"
name="media"
>

<source src="my-video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

<p class="vjs-no-js">Your browser is not yet supported. Please try downloading the google <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/" target="_blank">chrome browser</a></p>
</video-js>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
<script>
      var options;

      options = {
        controls: true,
        fluid: true,
        preloadWebComponents: true,
        techOrder: [ 'chromecast', 'html5' ],
        plugins: {
           chromecast: {
            addButtonToControlBar: true
           },
           airPlay: {
              addButtonToControlBar: true, // defaults to `true`
           }
        }
      };

    var video = videojs('my-video', options)
     // Chromecast
     video.chromecast();
     video.airPlay();
</script>
```

I'm loading the scripts as docs say:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js@6.1.0/dist/video.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/silvermine-videojs-chromecast.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>
```

Comment: UPDATE - Airplay works but chromecast does not.

Comment: Based from the [github details of the library VideoJS 6+](https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-chromecast), there is a caveat to using the `preloadWebComponents` setting. Because the Chromecast plugin uses the shadow DOM to create the `<google-cast-button>` custom component, the `<google-cast-button>` **custom component may partly render, but it will not be functional**. Please try the lower version of the [VideoJS 5](https://github.com/ricksancho/videojs-chromecast).

Comment: @jess i have same problem, using video.js 6.13.0. When i try to use video.js 5.x airplay doesn't working too...